# Xcode swift 3 don't know how to display an image where I click

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am a new programmer and I ran into a problem. I want an image to appear on the screen where I click. So for example I click on the top of the screen I want the image to show there and then if I click on the bottom of the screen I want the image to go there, but I don't want the first image to disappear I just want to add another one. Using swift 3 
Thanks

Comment: You should show some code

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed I can make a button display an image but that's not what I want I want to be able to click somewhere on the screen and for my image to show where I clicked. I don't have any code because I'm not sure where to start for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve that by overriding `touchesBegan` method of `UIViewController` this way:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self.view) // Get the location of the touch

    let image = UIImage(named: "anImage") // Create a UIImage instance
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image) // Create a UIImageView with your image
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    // Set the position of your image to be where the user touched
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: touchLocation.x,
                             y: touchLocation.y,
                             width: 100,
                             height: 100)

    self.view.addSubview(imageView) // Add the image to the view
}
```